# Multiple send request at one time

Tags: python, django

In a Django Project,
Multiple send request at one time how can be handle.
for example,
If multiple person hit send button at same time in the website.
How can be queue the request in Django-Website?

Comment: Every request will be processed separately as always.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description I believe you are interested in handling receiving multiple requests, and not sending.

Gunicorn is probably the most used and reputable library for this case:
https://gunicorn.org/